# CSS multiple input[type] selectors

Tags: css

According to the W3 CSS spec, something like: `input[type~="text password"]` should select input fields whose type is set to either "text" or "password", but it doesn't work! Did I misinterpret this line?

> E[foo~="warning"] Matches any E element whose "foo" attribute value is
>   a list of space-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to
>   "warning".

[CSS spec source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching), it's the fourth from the bottom in the table.

Comment: On [CSS spec source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching), we can see this note: Several sections of this specification have been updated by other specifications. Please, see "**[Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) — The Official Definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css)**" in the latest CSS Snapshot for a list of specifications and the sections they replace.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yep, you've got it round the wrong way. The selector is to search *within* a space seperated list.. i.e.

`<element attribute="text password" />`

you could find using:

`element[attribute~="text"]`

The benefit of this is that it shouldn't match:

`<element attribute="textual password" />`

To achieve what you're actually trying to do is a bit more verbose:

`input[type="text"], input[type="password"]`

Answer (score 5):

Just follow this:

html:

```
<div class="contact-form">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text">

        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="email">

        <label for="">Subject</label>
        <input type="text">

        <label for="">Message</label>
        <textarea></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Send">

    </div>
```

css:

```
.contact-form input[type="text"], input[type="email"]{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;

}
.contact-form input[type="submit"]{
    display:block;
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

I hope you understand it.

Comment: I assume you meant `.contact-form input[type="text"], .contact-form input[type="email"]` hint the missing `.contact-form` in second selector

Answer (score 1):

You are reading it wrong. `E[foo~="warning"]` will select any element that has warning it a space separated list. Like this: `<el foo="test warning etc" />`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `input{property: ....}` and it worked.

**For example** `input{border: 3px solid red;}`

Comment: Note: this selects all inputs. I once had three different inputs: email, radio and text; i needed to select only two so i did input[type="text"]{
 background: gray;
}
input[type="radio"]{
 background: gray;
}